# How to use typedef of a pointer variable of a structure to point to the same structure varible

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

```
#include<stdio.h>
//This program is about structure and there pointer
//
typedef struct{
    int i;
    char c;
}str1,*strptr;

str1 str[5];
strptr *ptr;

int main(){
    ptr = &str;// This is shown as incompatible type assignment **warning**
    ptr->i=35; // **error**: request for member 'i' in something  
               //not a structure or union

    ptr->c='d';//**error**: request for member 'c' in 
                // something not a structure or union
    printf("My structure values are %d %c\n",str[0].i,str[0].c);

return 0;
}
```

When I run this program one warning and two errors are coming. Please Read the comment lines for warning and errors.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typedefed `strptr` to pointer to struct. Therefore

```
strptr *ptr;
```

declares `ptr` as a pointer to pointer to struct. `&str` is of type pointer to struct and is incompatible with the type of `ptr`.

Change the above declaration to

```
strptr ptr;
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `strptr` is already a pointer type. You need to change

```
strptr *ptr;
```

to

```
strptr ptr;
```

Comment: The Errors are resolved ,But Still it gives warning as "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: @AkshayPatil 1) write `ptr = str;` 2) for more info, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31673572/2173917)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `ptr` like

```
strptr ptr;
```

because `strptr` already declares a pointer

```
typedef struct{
    int i;
    char c;
}str1, *strptr;
       ^^^^^^^^
```

and in main there must be

```
ptr = str;
      ^^^^
```

In this case `ptr` will poin to the first element of array `str`. This statement is equivalenty to

```
ptr = &str[0];
```

And function main in C should be declared like

```
int main( void )
         ^^^^^^
```

And there is no sense to declare `ptr` and `str` like globale variables. It would be better to place their declarations in main

```
int main( void )
{
    str1 str[5] = { 0 };
    strptr ptr = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the pointer typedef

```
typedef struct{
  int i;
  char c;
} str1;
```

as it obviously confuses, and use

```
str * strptr = &str;
```